# How to center image inside a button

Tags: css, reactjs

[image]

I want that .svg image to center inside my custom styled button.

```
.btn-close {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

My .jsx code:

```
<button className='btn-close' onClick={onClose}><img src={close}></img></button>
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `text-align: center` to the `.btn-close`? Since you are using flexbox `justify-content: center;` might work as well.

Comment: We'd probably be able to help you a bit better if we could see the source of your SVG as well as your rendered HTML, just to be sure… Oh! And remember to add an accessible label to that button, or alt attribute to the image. ;)

Comment: also try `justify-content: space-around`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the margin property to auto

[Edit]: I have just seen that the display is set to flex on the button therefore you could try to use **justify-content: center** as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Just some edit to your code. Your code works fine !.. For convenience, I'm just updating the snippet without React declarations.

```css
.btn{
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
img{
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
  <img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_206719.png" alt="X"/>
</button>
```

Hope it helps!!.. **Happy Coding!!**

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks alright, you are just missing `justify-content: center` and your image would be in the center like you want.

In code:

```
.btn-close {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  width: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  justify-content: center;
}
```